# Integrating Nowpayments gateway into elementor form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, payment-gateway

I have an elementor form in my wordpress site. I have added an add_action function to functions.php to insert the data to database. it works fine.
Now, Based on the data user enters I want to redirect him to a payment gateway.
I chose Nowpayments. I have converted the curl into php :

```
function make_nowpayments_payment($total_price) {
    // NowPayments API endpoint
    $api_url = "https://api.nowpayments.io/v1/payment";
    error_log('api url: ' . $api_url);
    
    // Replace '<.....>' with your actual NowPayments API key
    $api_key = '....';
    error_log('$api_key: ' . $api_key);
    error_log('$total_price: ' . $total_price);
    
    // Prepare the data for the payment request
    $payment_data = array(
        'price_amount' => $total_price,
        'price_currency' => 'usdttrc20', // Adjust this based on your currency
        'pay_currency' => 'usdttrc20', // Adjust this based on the desired cryptocurrency
        'ipn_callback_url' => 'https://www......com', // Adjust the callback URL
        'order_id' => uniqid('ORDER_'), // Generate a unique order ID
        'order_description' => 'Your order description here', // Adjust the order description
    );

    // Set up the cURL request
    $ch = curl_init($api_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'x-api-key: ' . $api_key,
        'Content-Type: application/json',
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($payment_data));

    // Execute the cURL request
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // Check for cURL errors
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        // Log the cURL error
        error_log('cURL error: ' . curl_error($ch));
        return false;
    }

    // Close cURL resource
    curl_close($ch);

    // Log the entire response for debugging purposes
    error_log('NowPayments API Response: ' . $response);

    // Process the $response as needed (e.g., extract payment URL or other details)
    $payment_details = json_decode($response, true);

    // Check for JSON decoding errors
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        // Log the JSON decoding error
        error_log('JSON decoding error: ' . json_last_error_msg());
        return false;
    }

    // Check for the payment URL in the returned details
    if (isset($payment_details['payment_url'])) {
        // Redirect the user to the payment URL
        header('Location: ' . $payment_details['payment_url']);
        exit;
    } else {
        // Log an error if the payment URL is not present
        error_log('Error: Payment URL not found in the response.');
        return false;
    }
}
```

I called this function inside my add_action function. I placed some error_log in the code to trace the code.
I received a jason body that apeears corect. I also get the following error. Anybody knows what to do forresolving the problem?

```
[18-Nov-2023 19:07:17 UTC] NowPayments API Response: {"payment_id":"6038762079","payment_status":"waiting","pay_address":"oooSKm12DTSTY1WAytbysjJMtL7g","price_amount":19.60784314,"price_currency":"usdttrc20","pay_amount":19.607843,"amount_received":16.327766,"pay_currency":"usdttrc20","order_id":"ORDER_6559hjk4edff4","order_description":"Your order description here","payin_extra_id":null,"ipn_callback_url":"https://www.pastmethod.com","created_at":"2023-11-18T19:07:17.629Z","updated_at":"2023-11-18T19:07:17.629Z","purchase_id":"4908400560","smart_contract":null,"network":"trx","network_precision":null,"time_limit":null,"burning_percent":null,"expiration_estimate_date":"2023-11-18T19:27:17.628Z","is_fixed_rate":false,"is_fee_paid_by_user":false,"valid_until":"2023-11-25T19:07:17.628Z","type":"crypto2crypto"}
[18-Nov-2023 19:07:17 UTC] Error: Payment URL not found in the response.
```

I received a jason body that apeears corect. I also get the following error. Anybody knows what to do forresolving the problem?